# How to insert NULL value on Date

Tags: php, oracle, date

I need to be able to set a Null value in DB Oracle if the user wont choose a date.

```
$createdon = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($_POST['createdon'])); 
INSERT INTO purchase (CREATEDON) VALUES(to_date('$createdon','mm/dd/yy'))
```

I am able to insert date if a user choose a date but if the user wont the date that is save on the database is "01/01/1970". Also, if i dont use "to_date" tag i cant insert record on the database.

Any suggestion on what should i do and how?

Thank you.

Comment: You must have a non null column. What is the structure of your purchase table?

Comment: Purchase column is set to accept null values

Answer (score 1):

`TO_DATE` is OK because - if you're passing a *string* (which represents a date value), it is a preferable way so that YOU have control over it. Because, if you pass '01.02.20', which is which? Is 01 day or month? Is 02 day, year, ... month? Who knows. Don't depend ond *defaults*. So, if you say `to_date('01.02.20', 'rr.mm.dd')`, then everyone (Oracle included) knows what to do.

As of `01/01/1970`: if you insert `null` but still see that value in a column, it means that

- column has a default value
- database trigger inserted it

Check both of these on that table.